# Are EF objects thread-safe?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, thread-safety, ef-code-first

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126616/is-dbcontext-thread-safe) about the thread-safety of DbContext (it isn't), I need to know if it's safe to handle mapped POCOs in multiple threads.

Suppose I have two objects mapped to the database using CodeFirst:

```
class Poco1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SomeProp {get; set;}
    public virtual List<Poco2> children { get; set; }
}

class Poco2
{
    public int id { get; set;}
    public Poco1 parent { get; set; }
}
```

In the main thread I'm loading Poco1:

```
var parentPoco = _context.Poco1s.Where(...).Single();
```

I then pass it to a task, where I create another object and change the parent a bit

```
var childPoco = new Poco2 { parent=parentPoco }; 
parentPoco.SomeProp = "Tasked!";
```

Then back in the main thread I add childPoco to the context:

```
_context.Poco2s.Add(childPoco);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I am not doing anything with the context in the secondary thread, but I am manipulating objects that are mapped to it.

Can I do that?

Comment: As long as you keep a worker class that holds the dataContext and dish out POCOs from that then everything should be safe as the dataContext holds the object graph

Comment: What do you mean 'dish out POCOs from that'? I just create them with new.

Comment: I don't believe the scenario you describe would be thread-safe, And unless you use some form of synchronization, you're likely to get race-conditions. POCO classes are just basic classes after all. Why are you resorting to threading?

Comment: I have an asynchronous MVC action, and I want to manipulate POCOs in the task. I have no problem with *my* synchronization, I'm worried about cross-POCO and internal structures used by DbContext - ones I am not aware of and can't synchronize.

Answer (score 1):

If they're "pure" POCOs (no change tracking or lazy loading), with no references to any other object used in the "original" thread, then you're fine. But most people use "impure" [POCO proxies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456853.aspx), which are not safe to use from a concurrent thread.