# Paralell execution of DB queries in EF (C# 4.0)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I would like to know if there is a way to replace this syncronized enumeration with something that enumerates both database results in parallel?

I've been doing some research, and as far as I can tell I have to create a new instance of the context for each thread, or perhaps even locking the same context instance until both results are completed (if possible?).

What are my options in .NET 4.0 (C# 4.0)?

```
using (var context = new DbContext())
{
    IEnumerable<T1> dfd1 = context.T1;
    IEnumerable<T2> dfd2 = context.T2;

    var result1 = dfd1.ToList();
    var result2 = dfd2.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just execute `ToList()` on two threads, for example using [Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Is `Task` supported without including any libraries?

Comment: Yes, it's part of mscorlib.dll

Comment: Remember that each task should create its own DbContext

Comment: @JensKloster What about my suggestion about loking one instance. Not possible?

Comment: @Johan it *is* possible - but EF is [not thread safe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126616/is-dbcontext-thread-safe), so it would be a big risk

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work as is, but something like this may help you get on the way...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static async Task<List<T>> AsyncToList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        return enumerable.ToList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = await enumerable.AsyncToList();
```

Comment: Ah sorry - you could always use the [BCL](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) to target.NET 4.0