# ef return wrong DateTime in another thread

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this code to get `DateTime` from database :

```
  private DateTime? GetLastWorkOrderFinishedDate(Guid scheduleId)
    {

        return _workOrders.Where(row => row.ScheduleId == scheduleId ).FirstOrDefault()?.CompletedDate;
    }
```

it return  `2016-09-04` when user click to a button . 
but I have a job that runned every 10 minutes and that job call Above code but it return wrong dateTime  `14/06/1395` .

the second value is `persian Date` but I dont know why ?

what is the problem ?

**updated:**

the value from database :

[image]

Comment: Have you set `Culture` for the threads?

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad no I have not

Comment: @GiladGreen Updated . no the value from database is : `2016-09-04`

Comment: I'm not sure, but perhaps you are using `Windows10` and the default calendar in the Windows is `Persian`. You haven't set `Culture` for your threads so it will use `fa-IR` as default culture. You can set `en-US` thread for `CurrentThread` or as a default Culture for all threads.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad yes your right .  I set ` Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` in my job and it works fine

Comment: More than 1 thread operating on the same DbContext isn't thread safe. I guess that you are using the same DbContext and beside of this problem you will hit more. Consider creating new DbContext in your new thread.

Comment: Did `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;` solve your problem?

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad  yes it did . why ?

Comment: Because I wanted to write an answer here, other users might will face your problem. Please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @AramKocharyan can u explaint more or share a link about new  DBContext and thread safe ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126616/is-dbcontext-thread-safe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we understood the problem is related to the `CurrentCulture` of the threads. The `CurrentCulture` seems to be `fa-IR` and that's why the the returned date is `Persian`.

**There are different workarounds to set default `Culture`, here are two of them:**

`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo('en-US');`

Or just set the `Culture` for the `CurrentThread` as you tried:

`Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`

Comment: Thanks. but why it returns `PersianDate` just in job? when I running projecct It works fine .