# Proper way to mock Dbcontext for multi-thread environment

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In entity framework, DBContext is not 
[thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126616/is-dbcontext-thread-safe?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). In order to support multi-thread environment, I had to initialize a new DbContext based on a connection string every time a communication with SQL is needed.

```
private void function(string sqlConnectionString)
{
    using (var dbContext = new DbContext(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        // talk to sql here
    }
}
```

Now the unit test becomes tricky. Since DbContext is buried in the code, there is no way for me to pass in a mocked DbContext.

I looked online but didn't find a good solution. Any suggestions?

Comment: Which IoC framework are you using?

Comment: For a simple, concise answer using `IDbContextFactory` and In-memory database, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956557/8644294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unit test this, I would create a factory for the `DbContext` and get the factory injected. The factory could now be Substituted with [NSubstitute](https://nsubstitute.github.io/). For the unit tests part the substituted `DbContext` factory would return a new `DbContext` with a connection to a memory database such as [Effort for Entity Framework](https://entityframework-effort.net/)

```
private void function(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory)
{
    using (var dbContext = dbContextFactory.Create())
    {
        // talk to sql here
    }
}
```

In the code of your unit test:

```
//Arrange
var connectionStringForEffortDatabase = ...
var dbCotextFactory = Substitute.For<IDbContextFactory>();
dbContextFactory.Create().Returns(new DbContext(connectionStringForEffortDatabase));

//Act
function(dbContextFactory);

//Assert
Assert.Something():
```