# Unit testing using EF Core InMemoryDatabase along with Moq mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, moq

I am using EF Core 6.0.x + NUnit + Moq. Below example is strongly anonymized, the real scenario actually makes sense.

I have a DbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{        
    public virtual DbSet<Foo> Foos { get; set; }

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
    
    public virtual void PreSaveActions()
        => throw new NotImplementedException(); //Here I've got something that must be done pre-save.

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        PreSaveActions();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

I have a method similar to this:

```
public class SafeRemover
{
    private readonly IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> _contextFactory;    

    public SafeRemover(IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext> contextFactory)
    {
        _contextFactory = contextFactory;
    }

    public int SafeRemove(string name, int barId)
    {
        using var context = _contextFactory.CreateDbContext();
        var itemToRemove = context.Foos.SingleOrDefault(foo => foo.BarId == barId && foo.Name == name);

        if (itemToRemove != null)
            context.Foos.Remove(itemToRemove);
        
        return context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

DependencyInjection registrations:

```
Host = Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
       .ConfigureServices((_, services) => 
       {
           services
               .AddDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDbContext")))
               .AddSingleton<SafeRemover>();
       }).Build();
```

I want to unit test that this method removes or not certain entities from the given set in database context.

#### Attempt 1 InMemoryDatabase + mocks:

```
private static readonly object[] _safeRemoveSource = 
{
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 1, new List<Foo>()).SetName("SafeRemove_FooExists_FooRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo2", 1, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentNameExists_FooNotRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 2, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentBarIdExists_FooNotRemoved"),
}    

[TestCaseSource(nameof(_safeRemoveSource))]
public void SafeRemoveTest(string name, int barId, IList<Foo> expectedFoos)
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;  

    var contextMock = new Mock<MyDbContext>(options) {CallBase = true};
    contextMock.Setup(context => context.PreSaveActions());

    var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>();
    contextFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.CreateDbContext()).Returns(contextMock.Object);

    var safeRemover = new SafeRemover(contextFactoryMock.Object);
    
    safeRemover.SafeRemove(name, barId);
    var actualFoos = contextMock.Object.Foos.ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedFoos.Count(), actualFoos.Count());
    for (var i = 0; i < expectedFoos.Count(); i++)
        Assert.That(expectedFoos[i].Name.Equals(actualFoos[i].Name) && expectedFoos[i].BarId == actualFoos[i].BarId);
}
```

When I use the `InMemoryDatabase` I am unable to check the value of `contextMock.Object.Foos.ToList()` after invoking `saveRemover.SafeRemove(name, barId)` because the `contextMock.Object` is already disposed:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur is you are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. Object name: 'Context'.

#### Attempt 2 Mocked dbset and callbacks:

```
private static readonly object[] _safeRemoveSource = 
{
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 1, new List<Foo>()).SetName("SafeRemove_FooExists_FooRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo2", 1, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentNameExists_FooNotRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 2, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentBarIdExists_FooNotRemoved"),
}    

[TestCaseSource(nameof(_safeRemoveSource))]
public void SafeRemoveTest(string name, int barId, IList<Foo> expectedFoos)
{
    var actualFoos = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } };
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;  

    var foosMock = new Mock<DbSet<Foo>> {CallBase = true};
    foosMock.Setup(set => set.Remove(It.IsAny<Foo>())).Callback<Foo>(foo => actualFoos.Remove(foo));

    var contextMock = new Mock<MyDbContext>(options) {CallBase = true};
    contextMock.Setup(context => context.PreSaveActions());
    contextMock.Setup(context => context.Foos).Returns(foosMock.Object);

    var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>();
    contextFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.CreateDbContext()).Returns(contextMock.Object);

    var safeRemover = new SafeRemover(contextFactoryMock.Object);
    
    safeRemover.SafeRemove(name, barId);

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedFoos.Count(), actualFoos.Count());
    for (var i = 0; i < expectedFoos.Count(); i++)
        Assert.That(expectedFoos[i].Name.Equals(actualFoos[i].Name) && expectedFoos[i].BarId == actualFoos[i].BarId);
}
```

Everything seems to work as expected instead of one thing... I'm getting NotSupportedException on `SingleOrDefault` method in above configuration of mocks:

> System.NotSupportedException : Specified method is not supported.

#### Attempt 3 (successfull)

I went back to the attempt 1 and removed `using` clause. Now it seems to work as expected, but am I safe to do so? Would [DI container](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=nuget+dependency+injection+.net+6) be smart enough to leave it entirely for him?
I can't find anything about that in the docs and I'm not that good at profiling to check it comprehensively.

## @Edit:

I've used InMemoryDatabase with derivered `TestMyDbContext` class. Still without success. I've got `ObjectDisposedException` on the following line: `var actualFoos = context.Foos.ToList();`

TestMyDbContext:

```
public class TestMyDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    public override void PreSaveActions() {}
}
```

Unit test:

```
private static readonly object[] _safeRemoveSource = 
{
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 1, new List<Foo>()).SetName("SafeRemove_FooExists_FooRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo2", 1, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentNameExists_FooNotRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 2, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentBarIdExists_FooNotRemoved"),
}    

[TestCaseSource(nameof(_safeRemoveSource))]
public void SafeRemoveTest(string name, int barId, IList<Foo> expectedFoos)
{
    var initialFoos = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } };
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;  

    using var context = new TestMyDbContext(options);
    context.Foos.AddRange(actualFoos);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>();
    contextFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.CreateDbContext()).Returns(context);

    var safeRemover = new SafeRemover(contextFactoryMock.Object);
    
    safeRemover.SafeRemove(name, barId);
    var actualFoos = context.Foos.ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedFoos.Count(), actualFoos.Count());
    for (var i = 0; i < expectedFoos.Count(); i++)
        Assert.That(expectedFoos[i].Name.Equals(actualFoos[i].Name) && expectedFoos[i].BarId == actualFoos[i].BarId);
}
```

Comment: Why mocks? The In-memory provider is used to mock the database during testing. Why mock the mock?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to prevent `PreSaveActions()` method from doing what it is supposed to be doing while unit testing. It decorates entities with additional values useful for auditing (e.g. timestamps, createdById etc.).

Comment: There's no DI code in the question either. If you did use DI and registered the DbContext as a scoped service *and* `SafeRemover` was also scoped and accepted a `DbContext` parameter in the constructor, then the DI container would track and dispose both classes. When you use `IDbContextFactory` it's up to you to dispose the DbContext. You *must* dispose it too, because any tracked objects will remain in memory until it's garbage collected

Comment: `to prevent PreSaveActions() method from doing what it is supposed to be doing while unit testing` that's not a unit test then. You're trying to modify the internals of the class you want to test. Instead of mocking modify your class so this *can* be configured. The method is already virtual, so you can create a `MyDbContext`-derived class that does nothing. Perhaps a better design would be to make this action configurable, eg through parameters or a callback

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I don't think mocking parts of "unit under test" disqualifies my test as a accurate unit test. Your suggestion is really clever but as you probably can imagine, there are certain situations where we are not able to change our codebase to make it easier for testing.

So let me rephrase the question then:
I guess approach from attempt 3 is not an option since Context is not disposed without using clause. How can I then make it prevail in attempt 1 till the end of the test without changing the unit under test?

Comment: You don't have to change the codebase, just create a test DbContext that overrides `PreSaveActions` and returns immediately.

Comment: `IDbContextFactory` has a single method, `CreateDbContext`, so mocking it will take more or less the same code as mocking the method and return a *new* object each time. The current code uses the same instance.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos got it. Please checkout my latest edit of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an answer from one of NUnit collaborator under this thread:
https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/4090

Long story short - make sure that you are creating new DbContext instance each time when it's needed and just reuse the "options" to point out on which InMemory database should they operate:

```
private static readonly object[] _safeRemoveSource = 
{
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 1, new List<Foo>()).SetName("SafeRemove_FooExists_FooRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo2", 1, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentNameExists_FooNotRemoved"),
    new TestCaseData("Foo1", 2, new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } }).SetName("SafeRemove_FooWithDifferentBarIdExists_FooNotRemoved"),
}    

[TestCaseSource(nameof(_safeRemoveSource))]
public void SafeRemoveTest(string name, int barId, IList<Foo> expectedFoos)
{
    var initialFoos = new List<Foo> { new Foo { Name = "Foo1", BarId = 1 } };
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>().UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString()).Options;  

    using var context = new TestMyDbContext(options);
    context.Foos.AddRange(actualFoos);
    context.SaveChanges();

    var contextFactoryMock = new Mock<IDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>>();
    contextFactoryMock.Setup(factory => factory.CreateDbContext()).Returns(new TestMyDbContext(options));

    var safeRemover = new SafeRemover(contextFactoryMock.Object);

    safeRemover.SafeRemove(name, barId);
    var actualFoos = new TestMyDbContext(options).Foos.ToList();

    Assert.AreEqual(expectedFoos.Count(), actualFoos.Count());
    for (var i = 0; i < expectedFoos.Count(); i++)
        Assert.That(expectedFoos[i].Name.Equals(actualFoos[i].Name) && expectedFoos[i].BarId == actualFoos[i].BarId);
}
```

Comment: Your `contextFactoryMock.Setup` is still returning same instance of the `TestMyDbContext` with `new TestMyDbContext(options)`. If you try to use the context by calling `CreateDbContext` twice in a row in your test method, you'll run into `ObjectDisposedException` exception. For a concise and well commented answer, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74956557/8644294